# PFQuery querying n number of PFUser and PFObjects

Tags: ios, relational-database, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com and I have a question regarding their relational database.
I have a User class (the default _User class) that as one of its columns it has a "friends" array. This friends array consists of pointers to other Users.

What I want to do now is populate a facebook-style timeline where at the beginning of the app I query my current user for its array of friends and its posts, but it also queries the user's array of friends and their posts.

I already have the friends array.
I can also query my current user, and I can query a specific user.

My question is, how do I efficiently query for posts on n number of users's posts?
While I can query specific users 1 by 1, this gets really slow if the user has 100+ friends since I would need to query each of its friends for posts.

Thank you.
PS: I'm using iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a `Post` class where you keep the users' posts. Then you can get posts of a number of users by using [containedIn](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/whereKey%3acontainedIn%3a)

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Post"];
[query whereKey:@"user" containedIn:friends]; //friends is an array of users
```

Or you can go with [matchesKey](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/whereKey%3amatchesKey%3ainQuery%3a). Some code from [AnyPic](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Anypic/blob/master/Anypic-iOS/Anypic/PAPPhotoTimelineViewController.m#L257-L257) example:

```
PFQuery *followingActivitiesQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kPAPActivityClassKey];
[followingActivitiesQuery whereKey:kPAPActivityTypeKey equalTo:kPAPActivityTypeFollow];
[followingActivitiesQuery whereKey:kPAPActivityFromUserKey equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
followingActivitiesQuery.limit = 1000;

PFQuery *photosFromFollowedUsersQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.className];
[photosFromFollowedUsersQuery whereKey:kPAPPhotoUserKey matchesKey:kPAPActivityToUserKey inQuery:followingActivitiesQuery];
[photosFromFollowedUsersQuery whereKeyExists:kPAPPhotoPictureKey];
```

Comment: Cool. I didn't know about the containedIn. I'll give that a shot and I'll report back